# C# lambda inner join with max

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, lambda

I created this sql query but am having a hard time converting it into a linq lambda. I'm fairly new to linq.

```
Select t1.* Fom msgs as t1
Inner join(
    Select fromUser, MAX(ts) as mts
    From msgs
    Where toUser='aUserName' AND isDeleted='0'
    Group By fromUser
)t2 On (t2.fromUser=t1.fromUser and t1.ts = t2.mts) Order By ts desc;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve same thing with `OrderByDescending` (linq extension) and `GroupBy`.

```
var messages = msg.ToList();
var results = messages.Where(x=> x.toUser = "aUserName" AND isDeleted="0")
    .GroupBy(x=>x.fromUser)
    .Select(x=>
     { 
         var maxitem = x.OrderByDescending(y=>y.ts).First();
         return new 
         {
              fromUser = maxItem.fromUser,
              ts = maxitem.ts,
              ... // remaining properties.
         }
     })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: With this I get "A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree"

Comment: Is this Linq to Sql?

Comment: Yes, I am connecting linq to sql.

Comment: Problem is `Linq` statement will be converted to sql expression that sql can understand and then executes converted expression.

Comment: In this case you need to split your Linq expression, try updated answer.

Comment: prefect, thank you! I moved the .where to the first linq expression so that I'm not returning the whole db.